# To find base and height of an isosceles trangle if sides and area are give

Tags: geometry, triangles

The area of an isosceles triangle is $60cm^2$ and the length of equal side is $13cm$. Find height and base.

Comment: Use area = $\frac{1}{2}a^2 \sin \alpha$ for an isosceles triangle.

Comment: do you know trigonometry formulas?

Comment: where $a$ is the equal side and $\alpha$ the angle between them.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Draw a line from the vertex at which the two equal sides meet, and extend it to the base of the triangle such that the line is perpendicular to the base. Then the big triangle consists of two adjacent (and congruent) right-triangles, each of which has height equal to the shared side of the two smaller triangles.

This height is also the height of the large triangle.

Indeed, each equal side becomes the hypotenuse of a right-triangle with height $12$ and base $5$, forming the very nice $5, 12, 13$-right-triangle. Since the bases of the small triangles add up to the base of  of the large containing triangle equal to $2\times 5 = 10$.

We can check our solution to find that $\frac 12 bh = \frac 12 (10)(12) = 60$ which is

The other solution is for $h=5,$ and the base of the half-triangles equal to $12$. This gives us $h = 5, b = 2\times 12 = 24$ for the large triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. If the equal sides are equal to $a$ and the third side $b$, then
$$
2a+b=13 \tag{1}.
$$
The height, perpendicular to $b$, using the Pythagorean Theorem, is
$$
h=\sqrt{a^2-b^2/4},
$$ 
and the area
$$
60=\frac{1}{2}bh=\frac{b}{2}\sqrt{a^2-b^2/4}.
$$
Hence
$$
14400=b^2\left(a^2-\frac{b^2}{4}\right)=b^2\left(\left(\frac{b-13}{2}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}
{4}\right)=\frac{b^2}{4}(169-26b)=\frac{13}{4}(13-2b)\\ =\frac{13}{4}a.
$$
So we get this way $a$, then $b$ and finally $h$.

Comment: That's an awful lot of machinery that you don't need.